# Getting the value of unselected the dropdown item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

By default, I have all the dropdown items selected. But when a user unselects one of them, I want to get the value of that unselected option.

I have tried the following option:

This is my html code:

```
<select class="ss-select" data-dropup-auto="false" id="ss_options" multiple="multiple" name="ss">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">One</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">Two</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3">Three</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="4">Four</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

This is the jquery code I tried:

```
$("#ss_options").change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

With this code, when I unselect an option (example: one), I get the values as `[2, 3, 4, 5]`. I am aware that I can do array subtraction to get the desired value, but is there some better of doing it?

Comment: `$(this).find('option').not(':selected').val()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:not` and `:selected`:

```
alert($("#ss_options option:not(:selected)").val());
```